# Blazor - how do I set a paramter from parent to child

Tags: blazor

I'm new to Blazor.

I have a header component that I have created and in the Page I simply have:

```
<h1 class="col-3">@HeaderText</h1>
```

Then in it's code behind I have:

```
[Parameter]
public string HeaderText {get; set;} = string.empty;

[Parameter]
public string Description {get; set;} = string.empty;
```

In one of my pages I make a reference to the component with:

```
@using components

<div><MainHeader></MainHeader></div>
```

Where MainHeader is my component.

So in my code behind of my page I want to set the header text and description.  I know for the HeaderText, I could simply do:

```
<MainHeader HeaderText="blah"></MainHeader>
```

and Blah would show as header, but for the description setting it this way is too much.

Can someone show me how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: when you say "in my code behind of my page" you mean within the `@code` (or `@functions`) directive of that page? or you mean directly the `MainHeader` tag of that page?

Comment: I've updated my question, I'm not using @code I've created a .cs page for the code behind, so each (the page and the component) have their own partial classes.

Comment: If your just wanting a more elegant way of handling the content/description. I think your after `Renderfragment ChildContent {get;set;}` marked as a [Parameter].

Comment: Does it mean that "Description" is hardcoded?

Comment: The description will get set in each of the .cs parent files

Comment: In the code behind for your page, you can create a property   string Description { get; set; }.  Then you can use the syntax in your razor file as <MainHeader Description="@Description">.

Answer (score 0):

Not really seeing an issue here: Is this is `MainHeader.razor`

```html
<h1 class="col-3">@HeaderText</h1>
<h4>@Description</h4>
@code
{
[Parameter]
  public string HeaderText {get; set;}

  [Parameter]
  public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

And on page you can do this

```html
<MainHeader HeaderText="@header" Description="@description" />

@code
{
  string header = "Your header";
  string description = "Your description";

  protected override void OnInitialized() 
  {
    header = "Header can be changed";
    description "So can description";
  }
}
```